# Guessing CPU Temp Based on HDD Temp

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, temperature

Is it possible to estimate the temperature of a CPU based on the temperature of the HDD. The reason I ask is that I have tried many temperature monitoring programs (in Ubuntu), but the problem is my MB and CPU are not supported by these programs.

My HDD is reading temps of 35-40 degrees C when its doing a full load of work.

If this is possible what would be a fair guess? 10 degrees? 20 degrees?

If it helps my case is rather small and the HDD is not that far away from the other components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's impossible. They don't track based on any predictable relationship. The CPU can change temperature in seconds and the hard drive cannot. You can't even reliably estimate the CPU temperature based on the heat sink temperature.

Answer (score 3):

They are completely separate parts of the system. Some applications are CPU intensive and some are i/o intensive. They don't even work on the tempatnure range.

Any relations you have found will render wrong after the second you find it.